# Passing Environment Variables to Docker Container When Running in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, docker, environment-variables, docker-container

We have a .NET Core project in Visual Studio (2017) that has Docker support added.  Our project relies on environment variables to configure itself at start up.  As we understand it, in order to pass environment variable values to a container you specify them as arguments to the `docker run` command using `-e`.

When you run the containerized version of the project from Visual Studio by selecting the Docker profile, we noticed that Visual Studio executes a `docker run` command.  However, we've not been able to figure out how to get Visual Studio to include our environment variable values when it runs the container.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to pass our environment variable values to a container it runs?

Note that we do not want to specify the environment variable values in the image since the values will change depending on where it is deployed to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can choose to include additional environment files to be passed to the `docker run` command by adding the following property to your .csproj file:

```
<DockerfileRunEnvironmentFiles>your_env_file.env</DockerfileRunEnvironmentFiles>
```

Comment: That worked - nice! The <DockerfileRunEnvironmentFiles> tag needs to go inside of a <PropertyGroup> tag.  That means that you can specify different .env files for Debug, Release, or another configuration.

Comment: <DockerfileRunArguments>
-e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
</DockerfileRunArguments>
Worked better for me as is pushes in the host values.  Two good options.  For this one credit to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164779/docker-run-command-for-asp-net-core-and-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 2):

I have a command line .NET Core application that consumes a secret in the input arguments, like
`mycli -ACCOUNT_KEY abcdef123=`. For debugging purposes, I don't want to have this value in my source countrol, so I set it as an environment variable on my system that I'm then passing in the command line arguments. This is what I did:

In the system environment variables:

[image]

In the project settings:

[image]

In the .csproj file:

[image]

In the .gitignore:

[image]

Comment: You could easily use User Secrets eg by mounting volume   `<DockerfileRunArguments>-v ${APPDATA}\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro</DockerfileRunArguments>`

Comment: @romi - no need for this, it is done automatically by VS (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2019#ssl-enabled-aspnet-core-apps))

Answer (score 0):

In case your **env variable** does not change frequently, you can also put them in the **Docker file**  , during the image-building process the env variable will be assigned to the container

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to right click on my project in Visual Studio and go to Add => Container Orchestration. This added a docker-compose.yml file and a docker-compoose.override.yml file. In the override file I was able to add an environment variable with no value. It selects the value from your system or user environment variables. This allowed me to pass through variables that I had set in windows without adding them again somewhere else.