# docker run command for ASP.NET Core and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core application with Visual Studio 2017. I've set up debugging to run the server in a docker container. The container is up and running, but I can't access the database, which is hosted in another docker container.

The database container exposes a port on the host. I need to tell the ASP.NET Core container to map the host's port to an internal port. For this I need to change the docker run command Visual Studio issues to run the container.

Where can I find it so I can change it?

Comment: Alternatively you can create a new profile under Debug and set the executable as docker.exe and pass along the application arguments and environment variables as required . Within the application arguments you can add the additional port mapping option mapping the host port to the internal port for the DB container . I looked up the full command that Visual Studio was executing from the output window and just copied it to the application arguments , it does starts the new container when executed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add the <DockerfileRunArguments> tag to the <PropertyGroup> section in your *.csproj file and put additional run parameters there.

e.g.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DockerfileRunArguments>-p 5000:6000</DockerfileRunArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change the command , however you may create a new Debug Profile and make modifications to the Application Arguments...something like this
[image]

Comment: That's very annoying. Why would Microsoft limit that?