# How to set docker network mode in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, docker

How can I set the netwerk mode to host in my ASP.NET Core docker container?
I suspect it could be in the launchfile, but there is nothing about network or other docker related setting/flags.

Where can I specify them?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker run command for ASP.NET Core and Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164779/docker-run-command-for-asp-net-core-and-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On launchSettings.json => docker profile add **DockerfileRunArguments** as in the sample below:

```
 "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://+:6002",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Dev"
      },
      "publishAllPorts": false,
      "httpPort": 6002,
      "useSSL": false,
      "DockerfileRunArguments": "--network=your-network -itd --name=web-api"
    }
```

PS: You can use any docker run arguments there.