# Docker and Visual Studio 2019 - how do I change the docker run arguments?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, docker

I've googled for answers to this and can't find an answer.  I have a launchSettings.json for my .NET C# web app - I want to run it under linux using WSL2 on a windows box, inside docker.  I have a Docker profile that looks like this:

```
"profiles": {
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path": "/app/certs/certificate.pfx",
        "Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password": "Password"
      },
      "commandLineArgs": "--network thegatehousewereham",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    },
```

but my environment variables are ignored (it gets Development for the ASPNETCORE ENVIRONMENT but it isn't from here, because I can change it and it doesn't change).  Most importantly the network command line argument isn't happening.

I've since realised that these profile key/value pairs are passed to the dotnet run command inside the container but I want the --network to be passed to docker so that it joins the network and can see the mysql database.

HOW CAN I DO THIS?

It doesn't seem to be possible.  I've tried running the docker command from the command line, but that doesn't really work (ie I couldn't get it to work) and besides, it means the tooling isn't being used and i want to use the tools.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If I probe inside the container I see that it has passed that --network argument to the dotnet run command.  So how do I modify the docker command it runs?

Comment: Please check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67989309/1529884

Answer (score 0):

I don't now if this is possible to do.  I've found that assuming the network is there - starting docker from visual studio 2019 - and then adding the container to the network manually - is the best I can do.